# How to plus mysql column value using php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how can I add or plus the value of a column in MySQL using PHP. I have an input field for `price` and in my database table, I have created a column named `price`.

What I want is, when I put some value in the input field (eg. 10) and hit the submit button, it adds this value to the value of `price` in the database column.

Comment: Use `UPDATE <TABLE> SET <COLUMN> = <COLUMN> + <VALUE> WHERE ID = <ID>`

Comment: Hi, do you know how to send an SQL insert request using PHP to Mysql?

Comment: @ankabout The question is about `UPDATE`, not `INSERT`.

Comment: @Barmar yea my bad, but just wanted to know if he know how to do a Mysql request thorough PHP at first place

Comment: @ankabout i need to update not insert

Comment: So see the first comment it's the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah that right @ankabout

Comment: Formatted and made question more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Update](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) query, like this:

```
UPDATE <TABLE_NAME> SET <PRICE_COLUMN> = <PRICE_COLUMN> + $NEW_PRICE WHERE ID = $ID
```

Comment: Probably want to prepare and bind values from the form.